# Perl forward SIGINT to parent process from `system` command

Tags: perl

If I have a long-running `system` command like `apt-cache search <some query>`, is there a way to forward a `SIGINT` sent via `^C` on the command line to the parent Perl process in such a way that all child processes are reaped.

This example does not have the desired behavior. The signal is sent to the child process.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie;

# long running command on ubuntu, produces a ton of output.
# replace with your favorite long running command
system("apt-cache search hi");

print("Perl did not catch SIGINT even with autodie\n");
```

I tried searching around for ways of capturing the pid of the child that would be created by `system("apt-cache search hi &")`, but couldn't find any, so I tried `fork`ing and `exec`ing the process and writing a signal handler. This doesn't work because `apt-cache` itself launches a few processes via the `clone` system call. Hand-rolling some logic to walk part of the process tree and clean up the

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie;

my $cpid;

$SIG{INT} = sub {
    kill 'KILL', $cpid;
    exit;
};

# long running command on ubuntu, produces a ton of output.
# replace with your favorite long running command
$cpid = fork;
if ($cpid == 0) {
    exec 'apt-cache', 'search', 'hi';
}

print "Perl did not catch SIGINT even with autodie\n";
```

I guess essentially what I want is either a way of determining whether a child process launched by `system` exited due to a signal like `SIGINT` so I can have the Perl script clean up after itself or a way of walking the child processes and reaping them in such a way that strange edge cases of process management are handled cleanly and portably.

Comment: `IPC::Run` may be what you need, rather than system. Or alternatively, just set `SIGCHLD` to "IGNORE" so they'll automatically reap on exit.

Comment: Here is a way to detect if the command was aborted by the user: see [Name of signal number 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862178/name-of-signal-number-2)

Comment: See also [How to start a process in its own process group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809034/in-linux-how-to-start-a-process-in-its-own-process-group-and-more)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the child the head of a process group, then send the signal to the whole process group.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use POSIX qw( setpgid );

my $child_pid;

$SIG{INT} = sub {
    kill INT => -$child_pid if $child_pid;
    exit(0x80 | 2);  # 2 = SIGINT
};

my $child_pid = fork();
if (!$child_pid) {
    setpgid($$);
    exec 'apt-cache', 'search', 'hi';
}

WAIT: {
   no autodie;
   waitpid($child_pid, 0);
   redo WAIT if $? == -1 and $!{EINTR};
   die $! if $? == -1;
}

exit( ( $? >> 8 ) | ( 0x80 | ( $? & 0x7F ) ) );
```

Comment: `kill INT => -$child_pid if $child_pid;` is this Windows-specific?

Comment: No, pretty much the opposite. Windows doesn't have POSIX signals or process groups (though `kill` can be used to send to a console app one of the very few signals Windows does have, Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Break).

Comment: So then what does negating the cpid do?

Comment: Sends the signal to each process in the process group identified by `$cpid`